# Powershell command to set IIS logging settings

Tags: iis, scripting, logging, iis-7, powershell

I'm creating a powershell script so I can create website hosting with a single command using the IIS Powershell Management Console.

I have the commands I need to create the IIS Site and add bindings for the domain names etc...

The one piece of the puzzle I'm missing though is how to change the default Logging directory from %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles to my own folder that's not on the boot drive of the server.

After extensive searching I expected to find a command along the lines of the following pseudo powershell

```
New-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\MyNewSite -name logging -value @{format='W3C';directory='d:\sites\site\logs';encoding=UTF-8}
```

Please could you show me with an example how you change the logging folder in the IIS Powershell Management Console

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration")
$iis = new-object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
$web = $iis.Sites["test"]
#set new logpath, must be existing
$web.LogFile.Directory = "F:\Logfiles\"
$iis.CommitChanges()
```

Comment: I tried this on Windows 2016 core server and don't see any log files in my directory

Answer (score 20):

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Set-WebConfigurationProperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults" -name logfile.directory -value $logdir
```

Comment: Thanks. This Worked perfectly for changing the default location. I have individual folders for each site though which I was not clear about in my question. Your code helped me find the answer on this forum post http://forums.iis.net/t/1174319.aspx

Comment: If you are using this with other IIS: drive activity in your script.  Make sure that the current folder on the IIS: drive is the root.  This can be accomplished with "cd IIS:\".  If you are in, for instance, IIS:\SslBindings you will get an error "Set-WebConfigurationProperty : There is no configuration defined for object at path IIS:\SslBindings."

Answer (score 12):

While testing the answer from this thread, toggling options via IIS Manager and PowerShell, I stumbled on something that has been hidden to me. In IIS Manager, choosing Configuration Editor and making a change, allows the IIS Manager to generate and display the script for the change in C#, JavaScript, AppCmd.exe and PowerShell. Just click the Generate Script option.

[[image: Auto Generated Scripts for IIS configuration changes]]

Comment: This is awesome, although it requires IIS 8.x or higher to get the Powershell tab.

Answer (score 8):

For changing an individual web site's logFile configuration, the original post was nearly correct. Instead of New-ItemProperty, use Set-ItemProperty, like so...

```
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$SiteName" -name logFile -value @{directory=$LogPath}
```

For changing the server-wide default settings, see [Andy Schneider's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4627715/80161).

For more information about the options available, see [this IIS.net article](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/logfile).

Comment: Small world... I noticed @Nathan-hartley 's avatar on [this other discussion in the tab next door](http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/iis-log-file-maintenance/). DSC sounds like the emerging approach for all this sort of thing

Answer (score 5):

This works as well, using the WebAdministration Module

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$site = gi IIS:\Sites\MyNewSite
$site.Logging.format='W3C'
$site.Logging.directory='d:\sites\site\logs'
$site.Logging.encoding=UTF-8
$site | set-item
```

Comment: This might have worked on older IIS or WebAdministration versions. However now property of a site to use is logFile. e.g.: ```$site.logFile.logFormat='W3C'```

Answer (score 1):

If you host multiple sites on a single server and want them to all log to the same log file, the process is quite different.  It took some digging to find clues [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa347469.aspx) and [here](https://forums.iis.net/t/1188137.aspx?Central%20W3C%20Logging%20How%20to%20get%20log%20stored%20per%20server%20or%20site%20), so I thought I would leave a description behind for anyone else with this need.

The following two statements will combine logs for all of your websites into a folder e:\log\w3svc.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter 'system.applicationHost/log' -name CentralLogFileMode -Value 'CentralW3C'
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter 'system.applicationHost/log' -name centralW3CLogFile.directory -value 'e:\log'
```