# Is there a way to programmatically check the last time each web application was run in IIS?

Tags: c#, powershell, iis, command-line

We're trying to clean up some applications in IIS.  However, we're not sure when some of them were last ran.  Is there any way to programatically check to see when these applications were last run either through C# or even PowerShell?  I'm not necessarily looking for a straight answer but pointing me in the right direction would help immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebAdministration module to get the location of the log files -

This is an example of how to set the log file locations change the set to a get
[Powershell command to set IIS logging settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626791/powershell-command-to-set-iis-logging-settings)

Then cycle through the log files looking at the last modified date.