# Enable iis logging with power shell

Tags: powershell, iis

I have windows 2008 R2 server with iis 7

I created a script to enable iis logging to a specific web site

I can change the following parameters:

```
$logdir = "E:\IISLog"
$logFormat = "W3C"
$logEncoding = "UTF-8"
$period = "Weekly"
$truncateSize = "20971520"
$logExtFileFlags =  "Date,Time,ClientIP,UserName,ServerIP,Method,UriStem,UriQuery,HttpStatus,Win32Status,TimeTaken,ServerPort,UserAgent,HttpSubStatus,Host,ComputerName"

Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$webSiteToEnableLogs" -name logFile -value @{directory=$logdir}
                Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$webSiteToEnableLogs" -name logFile -value @{format=$logFormat}
                Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$webSiteToEnableLogs" -name logFile -value @{encoding=$logEncoding}
                Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$webSiteToEnableLogs" -name logFile -value @{period=$period}
                Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$webSiteToEnableLogs" -name logFile -value @{truncateSize=$truncateSize}
                Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$webSiteToEnableLogs" -name logFile -value @{logExtFileFlags=$logExtFileFlags}
                Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$webSiteToEnableLogs" -name logFile -value @{enabled="True"}
```

I also tried to chnage to **$true** But also not working

```
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$webSiteToEnableLogs" -name logFile -value @{enabled=$true}
```

When I check in the iis management console (UI) I can see that the logging is not enabled although I changed the value "**enabled**" to "**True**"

Command to check:

```
(GI IIS:\Sites\$webSiteToEnableLogs).logfile
```

output:

```
logExtFileFlags      : Date,Time,ClientIP,UserName,ComputerName,ServerIP,Method,UriStem,UriQuery,HttpStatus,Win32Status,TimeTaken,ServerPort,UserAgent,Host,HttpSubStatus
customLogPluginClsid : 
logFormat            : W3C
directory            : E:\IISLog
period               : Weekly
truncateSize         : 20971520
localTimeRollover    : False
enabled              : True
PSComputerName       : #################
RunspaceId           : #######-#######-##########-#######
Attributes           : {Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute, Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute, Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute, Mi
                       crosoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute...}
ChildElements        : {}
ElementTagName       : logFile
Methods              : 
Schema               : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema
```

All the other parameters (for example: log directory") changed successfully but the iis isn't enabled

Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell command to set IIS logging settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626791/powershell-command-to-set-iis-logging-settings)

Comment: Is it possible that you need to use $true instead of "True"? I've never done this before -- or seen that hashtable syntax you're using for Set-ItemProperty, however, that might be one thing you can try. Also, does IIS need to be restarted? That could be a possibility.

Comment: I didn't duplicate.. The issue in the question was about changing directory. For me changing Directory is working but Enable the iis isn't.  In addition, I tried $true and still not working

Comment: Can you show how you tried `$true`? The way you have it in the question is wrong and I am also sure that is your problem.  `@{enabled=$true}`

Comment: I added the output and the enabled=$true command to the post

Comment: So the $true isn't worked and I also tried to restart the iis and still not working. FYI - from the IIS management console (UI) you don't need to restart the iis

Answer (score 3):

Run in powershell：

**C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd** unlock config `-section:system.webServer/httplogging`

```
set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\$webSiteToEnableLogs" -filter "system.webServer/httpLogging" -name dontLog -value $false
```