# How does one disable W3 logging using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

So far I have not been able to find an answer to this with Google searching or searching this site. I was wondering how one might turn off w3 logging using powershell.

To find the setting by opening the application you open IIS and then go to the server you are looking for. You should see Logging under the IIS section. That is the logging I want to disable using powershell. Does anyone have any idea how?

Comment: That works I've seen the other threads but I wasn't able to get it. Although for what I wanted I had to delete the location because I wanted it to be global. can you put yours as an answer.

Comment: Cool - ok, I've made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking ideas from this [Powershell command to set IIS logging settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626791/powershell-command-to-set-iis-logging-settings) question, how about:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' `
    -Location 'example.com site name' `
    -Filter "system.webServer/httpLogging" `
    -Name "dontLog" -Value "True"
```