# Powershell command to enable logging fields in the log definition of IIS Advanced logging

Tags: powershell, iis, advanced-custom-fields, iis-advanced-logging

I am looking for a powershell script to enable the field in one of the logging definitions in IIS advanced logging.

See screenshot as below.

[image: Enable Fields in log definition of IIS advanced logging]

I tried the following command.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "system.webServer/advancedLogging/Server/logDefinitions/[@baseFileName='%COMPUTERNAME%-Server']/selectedFields" -PSPath machine/webroot/apphost -Name VIP_Name -value "True"
```

I get the following error

> Set-WebConfigurationProperty : Unexpected token Input:
>   get-config("MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST")/system.webServer/advancedLogging/Server/log
>   Definitions/[@baseFileName='%COMPUTERNAME%-Server']/Fields Position:
>   93 Length: 1 Fragment: [ At D:\AdvanceLogging.ps1:10 char:1
>   + Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "system.webServer/advancedLoggin ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-WebConfigurationProperty], Argumen     tException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provide
>   r.SetConfigurationPropertyCommand

I dont know if the above command is the right one, can someone please help ?

Comment: Take a look at this Q&A --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626791/powershell-command-to-set-iis-logging-settings

Comment: Already seen, i am looking at advanced logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna add that filter in server node Please try this.

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/advancedLogging/server/logDefinitions/logDefinition[@baseFileName='%COMPUTERNAME%-Server']/selectedFields" -name "." -value @{id='VIP_Name';logHeaderName='VIP_Name'}
```

If you want to set filter in site level, Please use this command.

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site' -filter "system.webServer/advancedLogging/server/logDefinitions/logDefinition[@baseFileName='%COMPUTERNAME%-Server']/selectedFields" -name "." -value @{id='VIP_Name';logHeaderName='VIP_Name'}
```